# What determines whether a combining character will combine?

Tags: unicode, diacritics

If I have a string "\u05D2\u0308" I don't actually get a diaeresis on top of a gimel.  It sits to the side, as a discrete glyph.

I don't actually want the combined glyph, but I'm confused in general.  How does a combining diacritic like U+0308 decide whether to combine with the preceeding character or hang out on its own?

And how much of this behavior is specified in the unicode standard and how much is up to the individual text renderer or font?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it *does* combine.

[image]

You are perhaps using some environment where the text engine fails to render this correctly, but in fact your string is *one character long* (using the conventional sense of "character"), and a correct Unicode-compliant environment will tell you so.

Comment: What text engine produced that image?

Comment: It's the visible output from saying `print("\u{05D2}\u{0308}")` in Swift in Xcode on a Mac. But that hardly matter. Any decent Unicode environment would do. You would see the same thing if you were to go right now to https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php and enter `%u05D2%u0308` in the first box under "Decode/Unescape Unicode Entities" and hit Convert.

Comment: Or go to https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ and enter `\u05D2\u0308` into the first text field and hit the Convert button there. Same thing.

Comment: I do not see the same thing, neither in chrome nor in firefox (both on ubuntu)

Comment: Cool! Well, there's clearly a difference of opinion among rendering engines. :) I wonder whether the RTL situation causes this to be an edge case; one might argue that the diaeresis is _before_ the gimel rather than after it.